# Number.toString different prescision in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, tostring

This simple code `(1/3).toString(17).length` output different numbers in Firefox(16) and chrome(1101).

http://jsfiddle.net/3uLVw/

I'm looking for an explanation why Chrome's and Firefox's implementations of `Number.toString` differ.

Comment: What is the exact output in both cases?

Comment: @JanDvorak, `chrome = 1101`, `ff = 16`, I suppose. Since I got 1101 in Chrome's console

Comment: Wow. That's a _lot_ of septadecimal digits... a bug, maybe?

Comment: `toString(17)` must be causing the issue... if it is removed the numbers are the same length. the following also return different strings `(1/3).toString(17)` ... firefox appears to round the number somehow. i do not have a reason why though... http://jsfiddle.net/3uLVw/1/

Comment: @Adween base 19, 23 etc. also seems to provoke the issue... http://jsfiddle.net/3uLVw/2/ ... question is how relevant this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome gives a ridiculous number of digits for some bases. Using the common bases 2, 8, 10 and 16 works fine, but a lot of the other bases gives digits far beyond the precision that the `Number` type is capable of.

Test case: https://code.google.com/p/chrome-browser/source/browse/trunk/src/webkit/data/layout_tests/platform/chromium-win/LayoutTests/fast/js/number-toString-expected.txt?spec=svn7140&r=7140

Comment: any idea why it does so or if it's a bug? Is there a spec for the correct behavior in unusual bases?

Comment: @JanDvorak: It certainly is a bug, as the result is unreasonable. The specification (ECMA-262 edition 5.1) 15.7.4.2 says that the algorithm is implementation-dependent, but that it should be a generalisation of the algorithm in 9.8.1 (`Number.toString()`), which basically says that the number of digits should be as small as possible to reproduce the number with full precision.

Comment: I read your answer as "by design - here is tests for sources"

Comment: @Viller: Yes, they wrote the code like that and probably only tested the most common bases at that time, and later figured out that other bases doesn't work optimally. As they know about the problem and haven't fixed it yet, is because it has very low priority.